# Slack Golang attachment button click is not firing interactively

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am using the following example from `slack-go` at https://github.com/slack-go/slack/blob/62fceeadbaea9ead0f2209e82863b1ca81a24bd8/examples/buttons/buttons.go.  I managed to send the attachment as shown in screenshot, but when i click on the button, it seems like both were click but not doing anything.  I have tried SocketMode and non-socketmode, the result is still the same.  If I use normal button action as Block, then it works, but button action in Attachment doesn't seems to work.  I have created `/actions` in Slash Command as well but still not working.  Anyone knows the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.  I just need to add an Interactive Url with ngrok tunnel to my bot server. Initially i created in the `Slash Command` section but then I realized I need to do it at the `Interactive & Shortcuts` section. But my main concern is the UI click.  When I click on the button, both button grays out, is this normal ?

[image]